# Handle multiple soap versions in camel

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

A general question on how to handle both Soap 1.1 and Soap1.2 payloads in a single CXF gateway endpoint ( with cxf dataformat is MESSAGE)

I am exposing my camel routes through a WS endpoint, my cxf endpoint definition looks as shown below:

```
    <camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint id="esb-adapter-ws-gateway" 
            wsdlURL="adapters/esb/wsdls/product-v1.wsdl" 
            address="/esb/adapter/v1" 
            serviceName="ns:EsbService" 
            endpointName="ns:EsbServiceSOAP12Port" 
            xmlns:cfc="http://www.test.com/services/esb/adapter/v1">
    <camel-cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="MESSAGE" />
    </camel-cxf:properties>
</camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Here I use MESSAGE dataformat, because it gives more control & visibility over the fault payloads. And also I like it :)

The question is , I want to handle both Soap 1.1 and Soap 1.2 payloads at this endpoint.

How I am handling this at route level ?

I am checking for the incoming soap namespace and setting a flag through camel headers. Based on the header, I am setting the soap namespace for Soap response & Soap Faults.

The solution works fine, However I am concerned about the endpointName="ns:EsbServiceSOAP12Port" mentioned in the cxf endpoint declaration.

1. I cant define both Soap 1.1 and Soap 1.2 ports from the WSDL
2. I cant ignore endpointName option :)

Is there a better way to handle these kind of scenario's ?

Note: I am using XSLT to form the response and fault messages. For eg: If the incoming payload is Soap1.1 then I have a separate Soap 1.1 fault xslt template to generate fault payloads.

Comment: I dealt with the same problem. Ended up simply having it on 2 different paths.